I'm getting silent treatment as everyone believes I took leaves which angered management and now leave policy has changed
I'm a novice at professional life, as a 24 years old CSE fresher from Bharat (India), I joined a small France based company operating in India, with no more than 30 employee in my office.
I informed my HR 4 months before taking leaves, formally mailed her 1 month ago, even prepared an excel sheet to visualise and ensure that what I was planning is feasible and approved by the management.
I wanted 3 week leaves, which included 3 public holidays, each in one week. I took 2 WFH (work from home) on the first and last working day of week and 2 casual leaves.
Mind that I live nearly 2000 kms away from my home and I had to visit it for document works as well.
After I left, I observed change in behaviour and tone to everyone I usually need to talk to, senior, HR and even a co-worker.
I was later told that after I left, Director of my office made a new rule that if someone takes a day off, casual or sick, one day of WFH will be reduced for that week and if someone wants to spend some time at home, they'll be given 3 weeks (now 2 weeks) of WFH but they can't take any casual or sick leaves in those weeks.
This is absurdly ridiculous as simply reaching my home takes me 36 hrs of train + 4 hrs of bus travel, nearly 2 days and since my salary isn't that high, I can't go by air either, while majority of employees (seniors) are local or their home is less than 4 hours away by any transportation medium!
The incompetence of HR led to the anger of director, which he lashed out as these new rules, and HR cleared her side by painting me as bad guy in everyone's eye, and asked one of my colleague to tell me 'he should take classes on how to plan leaves!'
I wasn't there, nor informed of these incidents to defend my position, and everyone was giving me the side eye when I returned!
I've tried my best to maintain good relation with everyone, in professional and friendly manner within office space, and didn't bother to meddle in their private life after office hours, and one simple issue painted me as bad guy.
How do I deal with such situation professionally in future ?
I'm a guy with quick wit and precise sarcasm when it comes to response and comebacks, but this is not the time nor the place and I know for the fact that everyone won't take a joke sportingly, and can stain my career if they play dirty since it's just a beginning for me!
Suggested Edits:
At my current office location, all my colleagues are Indian. I haven't got in direct touch with anyone from different office yet.
WFH: Work from home, we can take out office devices and accessories and log into work remotely.

Are your colleagues also Indian? What about the managers? And what is WFH? Please edit the question to add the answers.

Edited!
Yes, all my colleagues in this office are Indian. I too was wondering why there is no formal post for manager, I haven't figured that out yet! I am starting to feel that there is no strict hierarchy in this organisation, nor there is a proper channel for delegating work, as I've been assigned ticket/task by my team leader, TL's senior (whom I currently work with), twice directly from the director of this office. There is no manager is in this office, which is odd as many of my classmate asked me to talk with my manager as well.

Yes, that's my real name, I do understand the implication it'll lead to in my current organisation if they found this question, would it be a no-no for my future application in other organisations as well ?

@TheDemonLord Changed it, please edit your comment too !!

@JustAnotherDev no worries

@JoeStrazzere I did work, I had 2 tickets assigned, I completed my part on time! Since govt work takes a lot of processing time after submission of required docs, there was nothing to do from my side in between, that's why I took WFH, so I can extend my stay to 3 weeks.

Even if you did work full days on the WFH days, it's very hard to avoid giving management at least the perception that you were gaming the system for three weeks' unbroken holiday. And saying "there was nothing to do" is tricky - why are they paying you if there's genuinely nothing to do in that time?

@FioratheFerret I do understand your point, but I cleared the same with my HR before even booking tickets, that's what I explained in the question itself. I even gave her a visual representation by creating an excel sheet and a detailed mail with each date marked on which I'll be present and on which I'll be taking day off. It was approved by HR, 3 weeks before the actual date of my vacation ! I even asked HR if it's not possible, inform me so I can reschedule my  leaves.

@JustAnotherDev - Who approves leave? HR or your manager (i.e. your supervisor)? Sending leave to the HR department seems out of place. HR would normally get involved if you didn't have enough leave and had to determine if a policy existed to allow you to use more leave then you had earned to date. Instead of another comment you should simply clarify your question by editing it.

But HR can only tell you what the leave policy is and whether you're breaking the letter of it. Your manager needs to be the first to know of leave plans, as they (not HR) will know the impact of a three-week break from the office on project plans, deadlines and commitments. You blindsided them and potentially brought them a lot of grief, hence the clampdown.

Thing that is weird about this place is there is no 'manager' post. My 'manager' is someone who delegates tasks/tickets to me, which not a fixed person either. The hierarchy seems totally out of place. In case of organisation I'm working for, leave is approved by HR, I do have to CC my 'manager', which was odd for me to grasp at early on, but then I thought maybe that's a different structure than I 'assumed' companies follow, as this is my first job. I'm going to leave by the end of year anyway, as I've landed an offer that pays double and is a well known company in my country.


I informed my HR 4 months before taking leaves, formally mailed her 1 month ago, even prepared an excel sheet to visualise and ensure that what I was planning is feasible and approved by the management.

If you have proof that you sent to HR all those documents, AND that HR gave you the approval ...
... then you are "lucky". Invite your manager to a face-to-face meeting, explain from your point-of-view what happened, and ask him for support:

what you can do to fix the current situation;
what you need to do in the future, to avoid similar situations.


and HR did NOT gave you the approval
Then things are bad, you practically disappeared from work without approval. Same as before, talk to your manager, but expect much less positive outcomes.

You have no proof of those requests, and HR does not want to cooperate
Same as previous. Talk to you manager. Things are not pretty for you.

For the future
First talk to your manager about your plans to leave. Sometimes, your manager will request information from the projects in which you work, if they survive if you leave, depending on the status and schedule of the projects. After the manager and the projects all agree that it is OK for you to take a leave, or make a change in the schedule in any way, follow the company's procedures to request the leave. Make sure that you do actually receive the official permission to leave, before doing so.
If you are not sure about how to request a leave, talk to your manager, ask him about the details, or where you can get the details.
The paperwork is always company specific, and even inside the same company, different departments or different location have different document flows. Always clarify your situation in your context. If you go to a business trip to another location of the same company, you need to follow the procedures both at your home location, and at the remote location - this is needed especially when the locations are in different countries, and you need to respect the laws of both countries.
So remember: your manager needs to approve your leave, not HR. HR is NOT your manager.
Bottom line: you cannot change the past, but you can improve the future.

I've every proof of what I said above, I document each and everything and have personal backups if I think that's gonna be involved in some trouble. I've mails, chats, screenshots of it. Every piece if information which is related to it. But they way everyone just turned against me, I thought it's worthless to fight uphill, that too alone.

You need to talk to your manager anyway. Clarify things with him, ask him to support you fixing everything else that was "broken" during the process. Without his help, it is easier to just look for another job - and hope that they do not hear about what happened here.

Will do. Although I am finding another job, and do have an offer in hand which pays me double and is a well known company in my country.
